# Как прикрепить документ как граффити VK?

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Интересует такой вопрос, как прикрепить документ как граффити без всяких программ, но возможно с API на PHP или другим способом?

> Знаю не по теме, но просто уже не знаю куда обратиться.

Comment: Дмитрий, здарасте. Нашли ли вы решение? - я столкнулся с такой же проблемой - вк переваривает .png избирательно, но по какому принципу - для меня непонятно. Удачно прикреплял png с вики, с описанием: RGB 24bit + 8bit alpha, когда сам пробовал сохранять в ФШ как .png 24 с альфа-каналом - не получается.

Comment: @Алексей нашел решение, просто при загрузке документа нужно добавлять параметр type=graffiti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, загружается всё через API. Получаем сначала `upload_url`: [https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?access_token=токен](https://api.vk.com/method/docs.getUploadServer?access_token=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD)

Теперь, когда у нас есть `upload_url`, загружаем на него png картинку методом POST с передаваемым параметром `type=graffiti`.

> В итоге мы получаем id документа, который можем прикреплять в сообщениях или комментариях, при этом, если нам нужно сохранить его к себе в документы, воспользуемся методом docs.save.